# Django request.path not working in inclusion tag template

Tags: python, django, templates

I tried to use request.path in the inclusion tag template, but the url does not show up. The request.path does work properly when used in parent template, and the inclusion tag works properly in all other places.
I enabled 'takes_context' in the inclusion tag, but I don't know if and where I should specify any path-specific context in the views.py.
Currently I use render() method to output the logic from my views.py:

```
def DJ_LastDay(request):
    p = Post.objects.latest('Day')
    posts = Post.objects.filter(Day=p.Day)
    return render(request, 'blog/DJ_LastDay.html', {'DJ_LastDay_posts': posts})
```

Snippet of my inclusion tag:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.inclusion_tag('blog/index_table.html', takes_context=True)
def DJ_LastDay(context):
    return {'posts': context['DJ_LastDay_posts']}
```

Snippet of my inclusion tag template (DJLD, DJLW, DJLM, DJLQ, and DJLY are all url shortcuts I enabled in the parent template, and they work fine outside the inclusion template):

```
    {% if request.path == DJLD %}
        Last Day
    {% elif request.path == DJLW %}
        Last Week
    {% elif request.path == DJLM %}
        Last Month
    {% elif request.path == DJLQ %}
        Last Quarter
    {% elif request.path == DJLY %}
        Last Year
    {% endif %}
```

I just needed to detect the current path for a conditional check to display the proper string in my template.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass request to inclusion_tag template like you did 'posts' in return

```
@register.inclusion_tag('blog/index_table.html', takes_context=True)
def DJ_LastDay(context):
    return {'posts': context['DJ_LastDay_posts'], 'request':context['request']}
```

Comment: Thank you NeErAj, I can get the url associated with request.path to display now, but for some reason I can't seem to compare the url generated by request.path with the url shortcut I created earlier (which were working fine in the parent template). {% if request.path %} returns true, but it doesn't seem to match any previous shortcuts I used (DJLD, DJLW, etc....)